# swift call 'self' error

Tags: swift, function

I created an extension for my class and add a function name `getFilePath`.
After that, I add some code still in the extension like below :

```
static let resumableUploads:AnyObject = {

    var url = self.getFilePath()

    /*bababaa*/

}()
```

But I got this error message "Use unresolved identifier 'self" ", so can somebody tell me what happened, and what should I do if I want to call the function?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a static variable. Static functions can't refer to self.
If the function you are calling is also static you can write

```
var url = [ClassName].getFilePath()
```

Or you can remove the static declaration from your variable